# Count occurrence of files with an odd number characters in the filename

Tags: shell, command, debian, wc

I'm trying to do a script that counts all the files in the system that have a name with a odd number of characters, only the name not the extension.
somebody can help me? 
I've done this but it doesn't work

```
find /usr/lib -type f | cut -f 1 -d '.' | rev | cut -f 4 -d '/' | rev | wc -m
```

with this I count all the characters of all file, but how do I count the number of character of one file ?

Comment: Provide some examples of filenames you want to find.

Comment: thank you both , mockinterface sol is to easy for me

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` command will print out the number of files with an odd number of characters in their name.

```
find /usr/lib -type f | awk -F/ '{gsub(/\.[^\.]*$/,"",$NF);if(length($NF)%2!=0)i++}END{print i}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Print all the file names with an odd number of characters,

```
find /usr/lib -type f | xargs -i basename {} | cut -d . -f 1 | grep -Pv '^(..)+$'
```

pipe to `wc` to count.